# Drag-and-Drop: How to make specific part of a SwiftUI view sensitive and highlight it during drag?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I have a custom drop zone implemented using an HStack and a Rectangle. I want to make a specific part of the HStack sensitive to drag-and-drop events and highlight that part when dragging over it.

Here's the simplified code I'm using:

```swift
HStack() {
    Spacer()
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(i == iS && j == jS && isInsertS == true ? .yellow : Color(.systemBackground))
        .frame(width: 3)
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 22)
.background(.clear)
.foregroundColor(i == iS && j == jS && isInsertS == true ? .yellow : Color(.systemBackground))
.onDrop(of: ["public.text"], isTargeted: $isDropActive, perform: { providers in
    // Handle drop actions here
    // Set isDropActive back to false at the end to reset the drop zone appearance
    isDropActive = false
    return true
})
```

With this code, only the 3-pixel wide part of the Rectangle is sensitive to the drop events, but I want the entire HStack (100x22 pixels) to be sensitive to drag-and-drop.

How can I make the entire HStack sensitive to drag-and-drop events and still highlight only the specified 3-pixel wide part when dragging over it? I've tried adding an overlay to the HStack, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a complete view code with all necessary properties to run and evaluate problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Binding that is managed by the onDrop modifier.
For example, I make a border around your Rectangle while dropping is targeted:

```
struct DropView: View {

    @State private var isDropActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(
                    i == iS && j == jS && isInsertS == true ? .yellow : Color(.systemBackground)
                )
                .frame(width: 3)
                .border(isDropActive ? Color.red : .clear, width: 1)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 22)
        .background(.clear)
        .foregroundColor(
            i == iS && j == jS && isInsertS == true ? .yellow : Color(.systemBackground)
        )
        .onDrop(
            of: ["public.text"], isTargeted: $isDropActive,
            perform: { providers in
                // Handle drop actions here

                return true
            })
     }
}
```